# Count the occurrence of each value in a Pandas column in a separate list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe column with unique values:

```
  c1
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

I want to count the occurrences of these values in two separate lists, and append the counts to the dataframe.  The separate list might look like:

```
my_list1 = [a,b,a,c,c,a,b,a]
my_list2 = [b,c,c,a,a,b,c,a]
```

So the final result would be a pandas dataframe similar to this:

```
   c1 c2 c3
1  a  4  3
2  b  2  2
3  c  2  3
```

I could make the list into a dictionary and create a dataframe from that dictionary, but this is complicated by needing to do this for two lists. I tried to make a dictionary of the two dictionaries, but could not get it into a dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
from collections import Counter

df['c2'] = df['c1'].map(Counter(my_list1))
df['c3'] = df['c1'].map(Counter(my_list2))
```

```
# print(df)

  c1  c2  c3
0  a   4   3
1  b   2   2
2  c   2   3
```